# Send input from database query to REST API

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a requirement to write program. Due to privacy, bot able to share the code. I just need ideas on how to implement.

Requirement:
There is API which creates tickets if the job fails. There is parameter in API -
short description'. Right now, if i run the rest api in postman, the value I am getting is default. I need this parameter to be dynamic. And final requirement is suppose if we are getting 20 rows from select query, 20 tickets will be created with different short description.

I need to get the short description value from a table by writing select query. (This is done and i stored the result in JSON object).

Now, the question is how do i send this JSON object as input to rest api so that it accepts the short description?

I have written everything in JAVA.

1. getting data from database by using select query - completed.
2. simple class to call the REST API by using the url - completed.
3. Send step1 as input to step2 - not completed.

If anyone can provide ideas or example code related to above scenario, would be really appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Let me know if the requirement is not clear or if more details needed.

Comment: You can parse your JSON object and loop through it can keep calling your REST api with the current short description. Is that what you are looking for? Not sure how you are currently sending the short description (header/body/query param)...

Comment: short description is in body of the api. i am looking for below question. send data from sql query as input to REST API parameter in body.

Comment: Isn't the query part of your Java program?

Comment: If you could add some pseudo code to your question, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, sure i will post pseudo code today. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.